# Вопрос по центрированию в IE

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте! Я новичок. Не удается отцентрировать страницу в IE, все съезжает влево, хотя в опере все хорошо. Центрировала так:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#body {
    auto;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Нужно уточнение: какой ИЕ? Страница имеет фиксированную ширину, диапазон ширины или резиновую ширину?

Comment: версия седьмая, ширина фиксированная.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

margin:0 auto, не нужно применять к тегу body, нужно создать див-обертку - веб стандарт `<div id="wrapper"></div>` к которому этот стиль и нужно применить. Нужно также учесть, что этот прием срабатывает только если элемент имеет фиксированную ширину

```
#wrapper{width:980px; margin:0 auto}
```

Answer (score 0):

В 8-ой этот способ работает,проверено)
Видимо 8 < так ,попробуй align="center" (HTML) а элементы через CSS по местам поставить.
Совет создай для IE отдельный CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то если так нужно позиционировать не body, а тот блок, который содержит все остальное в нем. Например

```
<body>
<div id='mysite'>
остальной сайт
.............
</div></body>
```

и в стиле поставить

```
#mysite {margin:0 auto;width:900px;}
```

Это как пример сайта в ширину 900 пикселей. Он будет посередке стоять любого экрана.